# Visualforce Converting window.name and window.timeout to make compatible with lightning

Tags: visualforce

Need to migrate visual force page to lightning , as window is not allowed in lightning could you help me on below lines how to make it compatible

```
var id = new String(window.name);
window.setTimeout( 'blink_hide()', 700 );
```

**PS**

From Anil's comment "may be my code was confusing this is the part in visualforce page which needs to be changed":

```
function resizeIframe(height) {
    var id = new String(window.name);
    var iframeElement = parent.document.getElementById(id); 
    iframeElement.style.height = height + "px" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) illustrates, references to `window.setTimeout` are allowed, though if you are referencing attributes the function that runs after the timeout has expired should be wrapped in a`$A.getCallback` function:

```
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        cmp.set("v.visible", true);
    }), 5000
);
```

According to the [Window vs SecureWindow Compatibility Table](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV) documentation, `window.name` is also available.

Your code doesn't make sense to me so I can't comment on that.

Comment: may be my code was confusing this is the part in visualforce page which needs to be changed                                                                              function resizeIframe(height)
{
var id = new String(window.name);
var iframeElement = parent.document.getElementById(id);
iframeElement.style.height = height + "px" ;
}